# Login with cookies with python

Tags: python, cookies, mechanize

I was advised to use Mechanize Module to login to a website via python script, though I originally wanted to use urllib/urllib2. Now, I've read the docs for Mechanize and it just isn't working. I have cookie support added to my script, and it seems Mechanize just won't do the job. Can someone take a look at my code and tell me if I'm missing something? The OUTPUT my script creates (MechanizeDat.html) should show the page once I'm logged in, which should include my username and account etc, ... though it currently just shows the login screen all over again. For obvious reasons, I'm emitting my password/username from the script, but you will get the idea (you should get a 'wrong username/passowrd combination' but you will see you just get the log in screen):

```
{
    import mechanize
    import cookielib
    import urllib
    import logging
    import sys

def main():

    br = mechanize.Browser()
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    br.set_cookiejar(cj)

    br.set_handle_equiv(True)
    br.set_handle_gzip(True)
    br.set_handle_redirect(True)
    br.set_handle_referer(True)
    br.set_handle_robots(False)

    br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

    r= br.open('http://www.zulutrade.com/login')

    # Select the second (index one) form
    br.select_form(nr=0)

    #for control in br.form.controls:
    #  print control

    # User credentials
    br.form['ctl00$main$tbUsername'] = 'MYUSERNAME'
    br.form['ctl00$main$tbPassword'] = 'MYPASSWORD'

    #br.form['3'] = 'Sign In'

    # Login
    br.submit()

    # Open up comment page
    posting = 'https://www.zulutrade.com/user#dashboard'
    #rval = 'PoopSandwiches'
    # you can get the rval in other ways, but this will work for testing

    r = br.open(posting)

    # You need the 'uh' value from the first form
    #br.select_form(nr=0)
    #uh = br.form['uh']

    #br.select_form(nr=7)
    #thing_id = br.form['thing_id']
    #id = '#' + br.form.attrs['id']
    # The id that gets posted is the form id with a '#' prepended.

    #data = {'uh':uh, 'thing_id':thing_id, 'id':id, 'renderstyle':'html', 'r':rval, 'text':"Your text here!"}
    #new_data_dict = dict((k, urllib.quote(v).replace('%20', '+')) for k, v in data.iteritems())

    # not sure if the replace needs to happen, I did it anyway
    #new_data = 'thing_id=%(thing_id)s&text=%(text)s&id=%(id)s&r=%(r)s&uh=%(uh)s&renderstyle=%(renderstyle)s' %(new_data_dict)

    # not sure which of these headers are really needed, but it works with all
    # of them, so why not just include them.
    req = mechanize.Request('https://www.zulutrade.com/user#dashboard', None) #None was new_data
    req.add_header('Referer', posting)
    req.add_header('Accept', ' application/json, text/javascript, */*')
    req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
    req.add_header('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')
    cj.add_cookie_header(req)
    res = mechanize.urlopen(req)
    html=res.read()
    file=open('MechanizeDat.html','wb')
    file.write(html)
    file.close()

main()
```

}

Comment: Wow, sadly, I'll answer my own question: I used Selenium for Python to do the job, it runs a Webdriver for Firefox, upside: it logs cookies, sessions, everything, straight from Firefox; downside: it uses the Firefox browser, so yes it automates, but you can't do anything else while it's running, as it is operating through the browser.

Comment: And Selenium does execute from python script, so it can perform any automated task on any account, logged in, perform calculations on page data, use A.I., and appears exactly as a human does when running.